# How to evaluate an "all or nothing condition" with array values

Tags: javascript, logic, structure, solution

I have a form with user information values such as names, contact, and address. The logic for address validity is an “all or nothing” condition - meaning if the user doesn’t enter *any* value for the address inputs then it is valid, but if they enter one address input (i.e street name) but is missing something else (i.e. postal) then it is invalid.

The form data’s structure is as such:

```
form: {
   first_name: {
      value: ‘’,
      valid: false,
   },
   last_name: {
      value: ‘’,
      valid: false,
   },
   //... more values here
   street: {
      value: ‘’,
      valid: false,
   },
   city: {
      value: ‘’,
      valid: false,
   },
   state: {
      value: ‘’,
      valid: false,
   },
   postal: {
      value: ‘’,
      valid: false,
   },
   country: {
      value: ‘’,
      valid: false,
   },
}
```

The following is the code used to test for that logic, if `street`, `city`, `state`, `postal`, and `country` are all empty, then everything is valid. But if even one of them is given a value, then the rest has to be supplied as well

```
const addressKeys = ['street', 'city', 'state', 'postal', 'country']
let isAddValid = form[addressKeys.pop()].value !== ''

for(const key of addressKeys) {
    isAddValid = !(isAddValid ^ form[key].value === ''))
}

console.log('is address valid?', isAddValid)
```

This returns valid correctly (when all values are entered & if one or more value is missing when at least one is supplied), BUT it did not correctly evaluate that all empty values (no input values supplied) are valid. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check that all keys from `addressKeys` are either empty, or (`||`) all are non-empty.

```js
const form = { first_name: { value: '', valid: false, }, last_name: { value: '', valid: false, }, street: { value: '', valid: false, }, city: { value: '', valid: false, }, state: { value: '', valid: false, }, postal: { value: '', valid: false, }, country: { value: '', valid: false, }, };

const addressKeys = ['street', 'city', 'state', 'postal', 'country'];
const valid = addressKeys.every(key => form[key].value === '') || addressKeys.every(key => form[key].value !== '');
console.log(valid);
```

This may seem inefficient at first, but this code will short-cicuit both in the `.every()` method calls, as well as the `||` operation. This means that if all values are in fact empty, there is no need to check that they all don't contain a value, JS will skip this additional iteration through the array for us due to how `||` works. Similarly, if all the objects contained empty values except for `state`, the first `.every()` call would stop as soon as it finds `state` is non-empty, and won't check any further values, as it already knows it failed its test. Then when the second `.every()` call does its check, it will immediately see that `street` contains an empty value, and will also short-circuit, returning `false` immediately without needing to iterate through the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

I think the xor in for loop is not right, maybe should do like this:

```js
function check(form) {
    const addressKeys = ['street', 'city', 'state', 'postal', 'country'];
    let isAddValid = form[addressKeys.pop()].value !== '';
    // check others, if others is different from isAddVaild; return false;
    for(const key of addressKeys) {
        if (isAddValid ^ form[key].value !== '') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


console.log('is address valid?', check(form))
```